# DetailsView - disable autogenerated buttons

Tags: asp.net, formview

I have a formview that I want to disable some of the automatically generated buttons on under certain conditions (i.e. certain users can't delete). For a detailsview, I can simply use:

```
dvInstance.AutoGenerateDeleteButton = false;
```

However the same option does not exist for a formview. How can I disable the automatically generated buttons for a formview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because it is a different web control. To achieve what you want you will need to specify the form's templates (ItemTemplate, EditItemTemplate and FooterTemplate) and then provide your own command buttons if required.

Hope it helps

Leo

Comment: I understand that they are different web controls, however I find it weird that in the declaration of both you can specify AutoGenerateEditButton (or the like), yet you can only manipulate that value in the codebehind of a DetailsView.